# Yosemite Mail.app - Rule stuck on 7 days

Tags: mail.app

I want to make a rule to delete all emails older than 200 days (they will remain on Gmail - I am using POP).

'Date Received' 'is less than' [7] days.

I can set this up for 7 days in rules fine - but if I enter any other value, save it then go back. It always says 7 days.

I guess this is a Yosemite / Mail.app bug?!

I found nothing on Google about this issue.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but wanted you to know you're not alone. I have the exact same 'stuck on 7 days' issue with Mail in Yosemite too.

Comment: I've found out more about this, but I don't have enough rep in this community to get over the protection on this ticket. However I have since found out this is a bug in Apple Mail, and has existed for a number of versions. The good news is the values you enter are actually recorded and respected, even though the UI says "7 days" all the time. To verify, set a rule to a number like '57' or something. Then, open `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/SyncedRules.plist` and search for '57' in that file. You'll find it close to the matching rule info. The value survives and is respected even restarting Mail.

Comment: How can Apple be notified?

Comment: Apparently, they have been, a number of times. Many radars have been filed from what I hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from TunaMaxx above who doesn't have enough rep to answer:

I've found out more about this, but I don't have enough rep in this community to get over the protection on this ticket. However I have since found out this is a bug in Apple Mail, and has existed for a number of versions. The good news is the values you enter are actually recorded and respected, even though the UI says "7 days" all the time. To verify, set a rule to a number like '57' or something. Then, open ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/SyncedRules.plist and search for '57' in that file. You'll find it close to the matching rule info. The value survives and is respected even restarting Mail. –